# Upload a video file to api.video, from blazor webassembly

Tags: file, upload, blazor, webassembly

I am struggling when trying to upload a video to api.video

I am on Blazor, .Net core 8.

This is their documentation : https://docs.api.video/reference/api/Videos , specifically, the "Upload a video" part.

I am able to do everything else , AccessToken, delete video, create video, ect...

This is what I have:

```
public async Task OnSelectFile (InputFileChangeEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.File != null)
    {
        long maxFileSize = 1024L * 1024L * 1024L * 2L;

        string contentType = "";
        string sourceB64 = "";
        
        IBrowserFile videoFile = e.File;
        string file;
        var buffers = new byte[videoFile.Size];
        await videoFile.OpenReadStream(maxFileSize).ReadAsync(buffers);
        file = Convert.ToBase64String(buffers);

        if (await videoClient.UploadVideo(currentVideoObject, file))
        {
            toast.ShowToast("Successfully uploaded Video", ToastLevel.Success);
        }
        else
        {
            toast.ShowToast("Failed to upload video", ToastLevel.Error);
        }
    }
}

public async Task<bool> UploadVideo (VideoObject video, string file)
{
    try
    {
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("Post"), "https://ws.api.video/videos/"+video.Id+"/source");
        request.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("accept", "application/json");
        request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token.accesstoken);
        request.Content = new StringContent("{\"bytes\":\""+file+"\"}");

        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        { 
            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Failed to upload video" + ex);
    }

    return false ;
}
```

What I'm getting as a response is:

> Bad Request, the file does not exist in the request.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass the file as a string, as the api.video API accepts only multipart form. You have to make sure that you pass in a file stream, by reading the file from disk. You can do that by changing the code to something like this:

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://ws.api.video/videos/:videoId/source");
request.Headers.Add("Content-Range", "");
request.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic base_64_api_key");
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();
content.Add(new StreamContent(File.OpenRead("/path/to/file.mp4")), "file", "/path/to/file.mp4");
request.Content = content;
var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
Console.WriteLine(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```